# Postman automation

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

Postman - I have a request which is in 2 part. In 1st part(POST request), it will generate a pre signed s3 url and in 2nd part(PUT request), a document need to be uploaded in the generated pre-signed url.
I need to automate this flow.
Can anybody please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Put the first request in the pre-request script, save the part of the response in a global/environment variable, use this variable in the request.
Here is a documentation to help you: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/